# How to hidden the output of Linux command launched from shell_exec()

Tags: php

Hi guys this is my code

```
<?php
  $res = shell_exec('curl  http://www.example.com');
```

I launched it from the terminal using this command

> php script.php

and this is the output:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1270  100  1270    0     0   5515      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 11545
```

I don't want to see nothing how can i do??

Comment: are you always making calls to curl? if thats the case you should be using [phps implementation of curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: I must to use this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are seeing that output because curl outputs its current progress to STDERR.

You could solve this with a redirection if you want to ignore it:

```
$res = shell_exec('curl  http://www.example.com 2>/dev/null');
```

Or, in the shell level:

```
$ php script.php 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Thank thisbis the best way

Answer (score 0):

You can use output buffering

```
ob_start();
$res = shell_exec('curl  http://www.example.com');
ob_end_clean();
```